# Assign labels to integers in bar plot legend pandas

Tags: pandas, bar-chart

I want to assign 'Single' to 0 and 'Married' to 1 and display it in the bar plot
 [image]

This is the code I wrote:

```
ds["Marital_Status"].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',color=['green', 'cyan'], rot=0)
```

plt.title('Marital Status of Buyers')

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) :

```
(  ds["Marital_Status"].map({0:'Single',1:'Married'})
                       .value_counts()
                       .plot(kind='bar',color=['green', 'cyan'], rot=0) )
   # if is string type
   #ds["Marital_Status"].map({'0':'Single','1':'Married'})
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, simply rename the ticks would do:

```
ax = ds["Marital_Status"].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',color=['green', 'cyan'], rot=0)

ax.set_xticklabels(['Single', 'Married'])
```